# React Native Google Mobile Ads Expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I have an application that I just started in expo. It was working fine until I added the 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' package to the application, but after adding it, it started throwing the following errors constantly. Although I did all the configurations, I couldn't find any way.

Expo SDK 0.48
React Native 0.71.8

"react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^11.1.1"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use Expo feature called **Expo Development Build**

this is step how to run it:

1. add expo package expo-dev-client
   `yarn add expo-dev-client`
2. create the new build

`eas --platform android --profile development`

`eas --platform ios --profile development`

3. copy the build on simulator or device
4. run the expo

`expo start --dev-client`

5. open the build on the device, you new package should be run correctly

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Expo is not able to compile the native code. For testing purposes, you can use the command `npx expo prebuild` and run the app on the simulators or on the real device. Follow Expo's [documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/) for more information.

Comment: I tried this command but it gives errors anyway

Answer (score 0):

react-native-google-mobile-ads does not work with Expo Go, you must use dev-client instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).